# I am having problems with my aplication in android

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I am developing an application in android, but i have a problem. When I click in the button suspend of android and click on the app again, my application always restarts and start in the launcher activity, but i wants that it does not restart, because i need to show the activiti that the user stays

Example

I have  Two activity  and two fragment, if the user is in the second activity and click on suspend and click on app icon, the activity to show should be the second

Evidence

I click on the button

[image: click in the button]

State the app when i click on the button

[image]

I click in app icon

[image]

The app starts again

[image]

But the app shoud show the next, because I stay in this

[image]

My code is the next

Activity one

```
package com.prueba


import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.content.Intent

class  MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Login)
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val myWebView = findViewById<Button>(R.id.prueba)
        myWebView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

     override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        Log.d("Save instance", outState.toString())
    }
}
```

Second activity

```
package com.example.automatizacion

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main2.*

class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    }

}
```

It is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.prueba">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:name=".Prueba"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon_prueba"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="28">

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.prueba"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:taskAffinity="${applicationId}"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="appunica" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
        android:exported="false"
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:taskAffinity="${applicationId}"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Main">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="${applicationId}.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please share your code with us for the `Activity` and not just screenshots.

Comment: maybe you called finish(); somewhere!

Comment: i added  the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share the Manifest so we will get clear idea ,because in code we see nothing which cause this problem so post the Manifest file.

Check if you are calling **singletask** in Manifest and **finish()** in activity.

Answer (score 0):

Search and remove the line
**android:launchMode="singleTask"**
from your MainActivity in the Manifest file to avoid this activity start when you resume your application from brackground.

Busca y elimina la línea
**android:launchMode="singleTask"**
de la actividad MainActivity en el archivo Manifest para evitar que dicha actividad se inicie al ejecutar tu aplicación desde segundo plano.